# Why some complex integrals are 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

This question asks to give an answer to why the following integrals are $0$:

(Notation: $\gamma(a,r)$ is a circle that has center $a$ and radius $r$.)

> $$\int_{\gamma(i,3)}\frac{dz}{(z-2)^3}$$

My attempt: All three zeros of the denominator are in the disc. If they were outside the disc, then this would be zero. But I'm not sure what to do with this next.

> $$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}z|z|^4$$

My attempt: The integrand is not holomorphic, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: The problem above was answered by a hint in the comments.

> $$\int_{\gamma(1,2)}\frac{\sin(z)dz}{z}$$

My attempt: $0\leq|\int_{\gamma(1,2)}\frac{\sin(z)dz}{z}|\leq\int_{\gamma(1,2)}|\frac{\sin(z)}{z}|dz\leq\int_{\gamma(1,2)}|\frac{1}{z}|dz\leq\int_{\gamma(1,2)}\frac{1}{|z|}dz$

I want to say $\int_{\gamma(1,2)}\frac{1}{|z|}dz\leq 0$ but $\frac{1}{|z|}$ isn't holomorphic, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: In the second one, obviously the integrand coincides along the curve of the integral with z, so that integral is the same as the integral of z...

Comment: This was not "obvious" to me. But I see this now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first one**: $\frac{1}{(z-2)^3}$ has the antiderivative $-\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}$.

**The second one**: It is the same as $\int_{\gamma(0,1)}z\cdot 1^4dz$ because $|z|=1$ on the curve.

**The third one**: $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, so the integral can actually be viewed as an integral of a holomorphic function. Alternatively, use Cauchy's integral formula $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=f(a)$ and apply it to the point $a=0$ and function $f(z)=\sin z$, noting that $\sin 0=0$.

Comment: 1. There is an antiderivative but there are still poles inside the integration contour. Do I need to worry about this? I think I have some mixed up concepts. 2. Thanks! 3. We haven't covered removable singularities. Is there another way to see this? I'm looking at the wikipedia now.

Comment: 1. Once there is an antiderivative in a domain, the integral around a closed path is $0$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis); 3. Perhaps $\frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ - Taylor's formula for $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ which shows that $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is an analytic function. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Comment: 1. Thanks! 3. Does the existence of a power series prove something is analytic or do I need to show more? The only way I know to show something is analytic is to show its holomorphic through CR equations.

Comment: @yoshi There is a theorem that guarantees that complex functions in one variable in a domain are analytic in every point of that domain if and only if they are holomorphic on the domain. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions.

Comment: @yoshi  I will need to understand better what you are actually allowed to use here... Are you allowed to use Cauchy's integral formula? What happens if you use it for $\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin z}{z}dz$? Note $\sin 0=0$.

Comment: No, we haven't learned Cauchy integral formula yet.

Comment: Then this is going to be the last straw: can you prove that, if you define $f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin z}{z}&z\ne 0\\1&z=0\end{cases}$ - that $f$ is differentiable (as a complex function) in $z=0$? Because it is obviously differentiable in every other complex point - and that will make it holomorphic!. You could try to calculate $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin z}{z}-1}{z}$ or calculate the partial derivatives as a function of two real variables ($x=\Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$) and then check CR equations are satisfied at $(x,y)=(0,0)$... Laborious, but will work.